# AngularJS 1.6.7 custom directive not rendering

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am learning AngularJS and I am trying to create a custom directive. In my index.html file I have the following

```
<h3><product-title></product-title></h3>
```

In my app.js file I have:

```
var app = angular.module('store', []);

app.directive('productTitle', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'product-title.html'
  };
});
```

The `product-title.html` is in the same directory as the html file and I am also running this on an Apache service so there should not be any issues with Angular's Ajax call. The template is not rendering for some reason. Does anyone have an idea about what the problem is? Also, side note, the console is showing no errors and the network is not showing a call to `product-title.html`. I also have the `ng-app="store"` in my `index.html` file.

In `product-title.html`

```
{{product.name}}
<em class="pull-right">{{product.price | currency}}</em>
```

Comment: works for me: https://plnkr.co/edit/9LswZT5CeYwKZeH5tEsq?p=preview

Comment: Can you show us what's inside `product-title.html`? Also, maybe it's a caching issue, try cache busting it by adding a random parameter: `templateUrl: 'product-title.html?v=1'` or try to open the page from Incognito tab

Answer (score 0):

It was a caching issue. Clearing the cache (using developer tools) solved the problem.